# Convert a hex string (0000 - FFFF) to UTF-16 and vice versa

Tags: python, hex, utf-16

I am working on a CPU emulator in Python, and I`m making a program to read ROM files.

The code that I have right now is:

```
ROMCHARS = []
ROMHEX = []
with open(RomPath, 'r') as f:
    ROM = f.readline(1)
    
ROMCHARS = list(ROM)
for i in range(0, len(ROMCHARS)):
    ROMHEX.append()
    ROMHEX[i] = [Here the Code for Converting the UTF-16 Charater to Hex]
return ROMHEX
```

It converts each UTF-16 character into a hex code, puts it into a list, and returns the list.

The problem is that I haven’t figured out how to convert the characters to hexadecimal.

I already tried:

```
number = int('0030', base=16)
print(str(number))
```

But that just outputs nothing.

Comment: Please add an example of the contents of `RomPath`.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by hex of a character. What is the hex of 'a' for example?

Comment: this question was asked and answered before here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999737/convert-from-hex-character-to-unicode-character-in-python

Comment: Maybe `[f'{ord(cc):04X}' for cc in ROM]`?

Comment: `f.readline(1)` will read at max only 1 character from `RomPath` so that clearly isn't what you want.  What is the real code you've tried and what is the expected vs. actual result?  What is the content of the file `RomPath`?  give an example.