# When generating texts in JSON, accented characters look different

Tags: python

I am having problems with code created in Python, and it is that when I generate some texts in json, the accents are not appreciated.

This is the code I'm using:

```
import requests

url = requests.get(f"https://images.habbo.com/habbo-web-news/es/production/front.json")
summary = url.json()[0]['summary']
print(summary)
```

This is the text that generates me:

```
Nos estamos preparando para esos fr&#xED;os meses de invierno con unos merecidos mimos en el Onsen japon&#xE9;s.
```

Comment: The accents are there, it is in Unicode Hex form. Try the solution from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999737/convert-from-hex-character-to-unicode-character-in-python

Answer (score -1):

JSON is *always* in unicode.
So you want utf8 encoding everywhere.

The url you mentioned sends this (correct) header:

```
content-type: application/json
```

Here is a snippet of the content:

```
"content": "<h2>Invierno en el Onsen Japon&#xE9;s</h2>\r\n<p>Hey Habbo, tus p&#xED;xeles estaban rozando el estado de congelaci&#xF3;n perpetuo....
```

There's nothing wrong with the webserver,
nor with the code you posted.

We do see some hex escapes that apparently you don't want:

- `&#xE9;` é
- `&#xED;` í
- `&#xF3;` ó

You're unhappy with the component that introduced
those hex escapes.
Find it and fix it.

tl;dr: You have bad data. Fix the data, not the code you posted.